# Handling BabyFTP MKD 250 response with Indy

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I'm using BabyFTP as an embedded FTP server for a Delphi 10.1 Berlin application. Even though I'm still not sure it's the best lightweight FTP server I can use with my requirements, it seems to be working well enough... except for one detail:

**On a successful MKD command, BabyFTP responds with a 250, instead of the expected (by RFC and Indy) 257.** Because of this the TIdFTP raises an EIdReplyRFCError exception which breaks the flow of what I'm trying to do (save a blob field to a file):

```
s := TBytesStream.Create;
Try
  Field.SaveToStream(s);
  MakeDir(TPath.GetDirectoryName(url));
  Put(s, url);
Finally
  s.Free;
End;
```

Of course, I know I could wrap the MakeDir line in a Try Except block and ignore the specific exception type. But this seems a bit risky as from the raised exception I can't be sure I got a 250 or some other real error.

I've tried looking if Indy's response codes are somehow configurable, but it seems they are hard coded in the specific methods.  Subclassing TIdFTP is not feasible as the methods are not virtual. I could customize the IdFTP.pas unit, but I don't want to do that as I'm working in a team and I prefer not having to distribute patches to standard Delphi units.

I could use another FTP server... but I suppose most of them have some not perfectly standard feature like this one.

Does anyone know of other workarounds? Remy?

Comment: Doesn't the raised exception expose the status code? Then you could just handle (and ignore) that specific case. Edit: see [EIdReplyRFCError.ErrorCode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/IdReplyRFC.EIdReplyRFCError.ErrorCode) property.

Comment: @OndrejKelle: nice... I was looking at the description (which is stripped of the response code) and didn't think of looking for specific properties of this type of exception. The try except with the test on the ErrorCode works. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ondrej's answer explains how to address the issue of handling a 250 reply in `TIdFTP.MakeDir()`.

Note that `TIdFTP.MakeDir()` is just a  wrapper for `TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd()`:

```
procedure TIdFTP.MakeDir(const ADirName: string);
begin
  SendCmd('MKD ' + ADirName, 257); {do not localize}
end;
```

`SendCmd()` is `public`, so an alternative solution would be to call `SendCmd()` directly and tell it that `250` is an acceptable reply code:

```
s := TBytesStream.Create;
Try
  Field.SaveToStream(s);
  //MakeDir(TPath.GetDirectoryName(url));
  SendCmd('MKD ' + TPath.GetDirectoryName(url), [250, 257]);
  Put(s, url);
Finally
  s.Free;
End;
```

Or, to accept *any* `2xx` reply code, you can do this:

```
s := TBytesStream.Create;
Try
  Field.SaveToStream(s);
  //MakeDir(TPath.GetDirectoryName(url));
  if (SendCmd('MKD ' + TPath.GetDirectoryName(url)) div 100) <> 2 then
    RaiseExceptionForLastCmdResult;
  Put(s, url);
Finally
  s.Free;
End;
```

Comment: That's IMHO a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Remy... I knew you would probably chip in :) This does look better. I had noticed it was a wrapper, but not that SendCmd was public. Since Ondrej agrees this is better, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

You could handle just the specific case of `EIdReplyRFCError` when its [`ErrorCode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/IdReplyRFC.EIdReplyRFCError.ErrorCode) property equals 250, re-raising in any other case.

```
s := TBytesStream.Create;
Try
  Field.SaveToStream(s);
  Try
    MakeDir(TPath.GetDirectoryName(url));
  Except
    on E: EIdReplyRFCError do
      if E.ErrorCode <> 250 then raise;
  end
  Put(s, url);
Finally
  s.Free;
End;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to have an On... Else Raise; ? As is this except block will not re-raise other types of exceptions, right? I know I should be more sure about this... but I am not really into catching and handling exceptions. I only ever use Try... Except to remap inner exceptions to a custom type I then immediately raise.

Comment: "else raise" is implied, ie. any exceptions not listed with an "on" clause are not handled and will be raised.

Comment: @Frazz if an `except` has no `on` statements, it catches all exceptions. if an `except` has `on` statements, those are the only exception types it catches. Uncaught exceptions do not need to be re-raised since they automatically continue up the call stack looking for a matching `except`